# Creating Walkshed using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I am trying to figure out the best and quickest way to show how far people could walk from the entrance of Disneyland in 2,5, and 10 minutes. I am trying to create a walkshed and do not have much experience in creating one.

Comment: Do you have the data? ie. a streets network?

Comment: Yes I have the streets network, a point showing the entrance to the Disneyland gates, and The Network Analyst License.

Comment: I know that there is a Drive-Time Areas Tool but I cannot find it.  Do I need an advanced license to conduct this tool? This is what I want to use. Thanks